# Formula for intensity and central bright fringe in Fraunhoffer diffraction from single slit

Tags: optics, diffraction

I want to understand why, theoretically, the central bright fringe has maximum brightness/intensity. And where does the formula $I=I_0\left(\frac{\sin B/2}{B/2}\right)^2$ come from? My book says it is beyond the syllabus.

Comment: There you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_(mathematics). It's basically a Fourier transformation of a rectangular step function.

Comment: @CuriousOne I do not understand higher mathematics

Comment: That's probably the reason why your syllabus is avoiding to walk you trough the mathematics of the derivation. If you would like a handwaving explanation without math, it goes like this: every point of the slit sends out a spherical wave. All of these waves interfere, both constructively and destructively. Constructive interference is the strongest where all waves arrive with the same phase, i.e. at the angle at which the distance from the observer is exactly the same. That happens to be in the centerline of the slit. For the general formula we calculate this interference with an integral.

Comment: @GunjanChhablani: So, what should we do? It obviously shows lack of research-effort.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I would count it as an answer:)

Comment: @user36790: A very handwaving one and I am sure we have a much better answer than this, already.

Comment: @user36790 How does it show a lack of effort when i'm just in high school and dont get "Fourier transformation" ? I was guessing there if there could be a simpler method to get the equation.

Comment: @CuriousOne That was a good explanation :)

Comment: @GunjanChhablani: Depends on your definition of "simple". Newton came up with a lot of congenial geometric ways to derive basic and not so basic results of classical mechanics. You will have to go back to reading his Principia if you want to see them. We don't teach mechanics Newton's way because we have easier, higher level ways of working the math.  I think you are more than bright enough to cut your teeth at calculus and Fourier transforms. It will be time well spent. You can try to work trough non-calculus ways of deriving the formula or you can learn the tools. The latter is better.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am preparing the chapter for an examination right now. I'll surely try my best to understand the derivation procided in the wikipedia article when i get some time.

Comment: @GunjanChhablani: Good luck! I know you will be able to understand.